# My app is getting crashed when logging out ? In Logcat it shows NullPointerException, null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-firestore

This is class file code to like and count photo likes. I'm getting null pointer exception

```
    //likes counter

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + blogPostId + "/Likes").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                int count = documentSnapshots.size();
                holder.updateLikesCount(count);

            }else{

                holder.updateLikesCount(0);

            }

        }
    });
```

This is Logcat Details :

```
 Process: com.example.suraj.photoblog, PID: 24823
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.suraj.photoblog.BlogRecyclerAdapter$1.onEvent(BlogRecyclerAdapter.java:107)
        at com.example.suraj.photoblog.BlogRecyclerAdapter$1.onEvent(BlogRecyclerAdapter.java:103)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzi.onEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: Please help me..... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

At this line `if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){` you are getting the error, you should be checking that reference if it is null.

So your code there should be:

```
if ( documentSnapshots != null && !documentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
```

Comment: Thank You very much